Verifiable (threshold) OPRF with committed inputs and composability?
I'm looking for a verifiable (threshold) OPRF that supports committed inputs and is composable with other protocols.
Concretely, I'd like to be able to do the following: Assume I hold a verifiable credential cred for my passport id (i.e., a signature cred = SIGN(id) from a credential issuer). Now I'd like to turn this into a pseudonymous identifier pid using a threshold OPRF (i.e., pid = OPRF(id)). Finally, I'd like to prove to a third party that I possess some credential cert for some id that yields pseudo-id pid (i.e., VerifySIG(cert, id) = 1 and VerifyOPRF(id, pid) = 1) without revealing cert or id (i.e., only revealing pid).
I know that BBS signatures allow proving knowledge of signatures and I believe (threshold) BLS signatures can be used as a (threshold) OPRF. But I'm not sure whether BLS works for committed inputs and how all of this can be fitted with zero knowledge proofs to prove the respective relations.
Any hints on the feasibility of this approach, or suggestions for alternatives are appreciated.
